# Angular 2 Handling external Javascript scripts

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm writing an Angular 2 app that uses a HTML template design that I downloaded from a third party.  All of the script tags rely on jquery.  2 of them registers events after the document is loaded, 1 of them explicity calls an "init" method.

My CSS LOOKS correct but without those js files executing at the right time (after the template component is loaded i.e. AfterViewInit), none of the interactivity with the template works correctly.

Currently, I have the 3 script tags on my index.html page which I know won't work because the actual html isn't loaded yet.  My guess is that I need to implement AfterViewInit in my template component, but I don't know what exactly to do in that method to load the script files and call a js method in one of those files explicitly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:

Further clarification: I bought the template which provided the code.  I am hosting the js files in my solution but I can't actually post them anywhere due to license restrictions.  I CAN change them but would prefer NOT to in the case that there are any updates to the template later.

One of the files is a vendor file contains 3rd party dependencies for the template.  The 2nd file extends Twitter's Bootstrap.js.  I believe those two files are fine as they do not have any methods being called, they just define methods for use later.

The third defines methods specific to the template in the format I gave in the example.  This file executes one of the methods it defines by itself.  It calls App.init() after defining all of it's methods.

Right now, the App.init() method is called BEFORE the html of my component is rendered (I understand why this would happen since I currently have the app.js file for this script file on the index page which renders before Angular gets a chance to render the view that requires the code).  I need to call that App.init AFTER the view is rendered so that hooks to elements on the page can occur (i.e. $(".menu-item") actually returns some results).

Comment: Have the angular code inject the template jQuery files instead that way you control when they are loaded.

Comment: The question needs an explanation what happens inside those scripts. With code examples. *js files executing at the right time* requirement makes little sense, because there may be multiple component instances. Should the scripts be loaded and executed multiple times?

Comment: @GillesC - What do you mean by inject the template jquery files?  How would I do that exactly?

Comment: @estus - As an example.  One of the files is written in this fashion: 

'use strict';

(function ($) {
  'use strict';
    var App = {...}
  App.init();
})(jQuery);

The App.init() happens way before any of the html is actually loaded via the component (the user has to log in before they actually get to the page with the template html and currently the code above executes as soon as the index.html page is loaded).  I'm thinking that I need to load the js file in the AfterViewInit event of the component that has the html.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make anything clearer. It isn't obvious if the scripts are hosted by third party or by you (in the last case refactoring is a first choice). Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can clearly explain how the things are done (jQuery scripts may be simplified but it is important to show what exactly they do).

Comment: @estus - I updated the question to be more specific.  If I add the App object defined in that third js file to the global window object, I can call window.App.init() in my component's AfterViewInit method and everything begins working as it should.  This feels like a hack though and I'd prefer to find a way to load the file directly in that AfterViewInit method.

Comment: Is there a reason why the files should be kept separate and not as a part of app bundle? In fact, loading JS files from a component is a hack indeed that should be avoided.